# Add mx record in linux - switching from postfix to hosting

Tags: networking, server, dns, postfix

I'm using `ionos` hosting and my domain's name servers are pointing to my static ip address where I've a linux server running.

Recently I'm facing some issues with `postfix`, emails aren't sending and receiving properly and long queues. so I'd like to use the mail servers from `ionos`. I contacted the support and they are telling to add the MX record in my server to map to the ionos email server.

I've my nameserver in `resolv.conf` but not sure where we add the MX record in the `ubuntu` server. I spent lot of time online but couldn't find any solutions. Any ideas about where do I change this ?